# Tenkeyless keyboard recommendation

Tags: keyboards

I really like the ergonomics of a tenkeyless keyboard.

But I work in an office environment, and am a loud and aggressive typer.

It seems like EVERYTHING I find for tenkeyless on Amazon is mechanical switches, and most commonly blue mechanical switches (the loudest ones).

I am just looking for a quality tenkeyless keyboard that is quiet. I also prefer a little bit of tactile feedback (maybe cherry red are not for me).

DO any quiet tenkeyless keyboards exist?

Comment: Red and Brown switches are the most common non-clicky. As an example: https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/shop/index.php?l=product_list&c=27

Comment: MX Silents, a quiet Reds-like linear switch, also exist. Noise can also be reduced by adding O-rings. However, if you demand absolute quiet, there's also Apple's 60%-ish chicklet design.

Answer (score 1):

There are new MX switches out that are called MX Silent Reds. It's the combination of the typical Red switch, but silent at bottoming out, which is where the MX Red gets it's sound. In theory these are good, but are going to be hard to find for awhile. Here's this one from Corsair that I like, except for the price and the fact that it isn't tenkeyless.

[Corsial K70 RGB MX Silent Red](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D5S3LZW)

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy a Durgods TKL (K320) with Mx Browns (mentioned above, has bump but no click). I would use in an office but if you are heavy on the keys it may be worth ordering a key tester that has a few kinds and types for you to test the volume and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the topre switches, they are not so loud, and from what I've heard it's qiute an experience.

This one for example: [Realforce 87U on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MV7TMNQ)

You can check a review here: [YouTube Review on Realforce 87U](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Sc4hB6m8-s)

They are also mechanical but they are less loud than Cherry MX. Myself, I have a Ducky Zero with brown MX but I don't have issues with the clicky noises :)

Answer (score 0):

As Mihail said you could try a topre switch, however these can be a lot more expensive than the traditional mx style mechanical switches ( that's if you regard topre as mechanical).

https://www.massdrop.com/buy/massdrop-alt-mechanical-keyboard 
This isn't tenkeyless as it is missing some of the function keys ( the lesser used ones and some of the keys like print screen and end).

If you consider getting this keyboard I would recommend getting one of the halo switches ( both are tactile) as browns are quite naff imo. Here is an article comparing the difference. ( I use halo trues personally).
https://www.tomshardware.com/news/input-club-halo-true-halo-clear-mechanical-switches,34443.html

On the other hand the Code Keyboard and the WASD keyboards also have some good tenkeyless boards from memory.